# clang vs gcc - CTAD of struct deriving from template parameter

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, ctad, deduction-guide

Consider the following code:

```cpp
template <typename B>
struct D : B { };

D d{[]{ }};
```

- gcc 12.x accepts it and deduces `d` to be `D</* type of lambda */>` as expected.
- clang 14.x rejects it with the following error:

```
<source>:4:3: error: no viable constructor 
              or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'D'
D d{[]{ }};
  ^

<source>:2:8: note: candidate template ignored: 
              could not match 'D<B>' against '(lambda at <source>:4:5)'
struct D : B { };
       ^

<source>:2:8: note: candidate function template not viable: 
              requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x187x3GW9)

---

Which compiler is behaving correctly here?

Comment: Related/near-dupe: [Template argument deduction for parenthesized initialization of aggregates in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961473/template-argument-deduction-for-parenthesized-initialization-of-aggregates-in-c).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the code snippet, no deduction guide has been provided. [P1816](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1816r0.pdf) added deduction guides for aggregate class templates in C++20, by requiring that an *aggregate deduction candidate* is generated.

The code is valid, but Clang just [doesn't support P1816](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) yet.

Adding a deduction guide allows this to [compile in Clang](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1MT59a3K1) as well.

```
template <typename B> D(B) -> D<B>;
```